# Installing September 2016 CU

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

I am going to install the September 2016 CU for SharePoint 2013 server this weekend. Do I first need to install the same CU for foundation or does the server CU cover it all?

Answer (score 1):

This is the full server package for SharePoint Server 2013 and contains also the SharePoint Foundation 2013 fixes so you need only this package.

New since April 2015:

- You need to have SP1 installed!

Official link [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joerg_sinemus/2016/09/15/sharepoint-2013-september-2016-cu/)

Answer (score 0):

As @Ransher Singh mentioned , the full package of SharePoint Server CU will include the Foundation CU.

But I suggest to you to don't install Sept CU 2016 now ,it was launched a short time ago , no more people try it,

Meanwhile, you should check the following important points before applying CU

- Get a farm backup before applying CU, (you can't do CU rollback)
- Before applying the CU on production , Try to apply it on test farm.
- After installing CU , you should run the configuration wizard to apply this patch.
- Maks sure that at least the service pack 1 has been installed or above
- It's preferred to install the CU that will solve a specific issue in your farm, so check Improvements and issues that this cumulative update fixes section for CU.

Comment: Thanks. Sept 2016 has been installed and undergone a full UAT on another site similar to is with the same 3rd party add-ons. I will be installing on the test fame first